# Is it safe to store the oauth2 token in the UserProperties?

Tags: security, google-apps-script, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I am using the the [oauth2](https://github.com/gsuitedevs/apps-script-oauth2) library to impersionate a service account with a user in order to access the google api in the context of that user similar to this example:

```
function getService() {
return OAuth2.createService('GoogleDrive:' + USER_EMAIL)
  // Set the endpoint URL.
  .setTokenUrl('https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token')

  // Set the private key and issuer.
  .setPrivateKey(PRIVATE_KEY)
  .setIssuer(CLIENT_EMAIL)

  // Set the name of the user to impersonate. This will only work for
  // Google Apps for Work/EDU accounts whose admin has setup domain-wide
  // delegation:
  // https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#delegatingauthority
  .setSubject(USER_EMAIL)

  // Set the property store where authorized tokens should be persisted.
  .setPropertyStore(PropertiesService.getUserProperties())

  // Set the scope. This must match one of the scopes configured during the
  // setup of domain-wide delegation.
  .setScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive');
}
```

As you can see, I am storing the bearer token in the Userproperties and I am wondering if this has some security implications.

- Can the user access this token somewhere (afaik there is no UI in the Gsuite for that?)
- What can the user actually do with this token (I think it will expire in 1 hour right?)

Comment: I'm not sure this is your expected result. So I answer it as comments. A1: When `PropertiesService.getUserProperties()` is used, in the current stage, the user can retrieve the saved values on only the same GAS project. The values cannot be retrieved with the Google APIs and UI. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/properties#comparison_of_property_stores) A2: At Google, the default value of `expires_in` of the access token is 3600 seconds. About this, you can check this using this curl command of `curl "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?access_token=###"`.

Comment: I would like to approach the answer by discussing about the result you expect.

Comment: ", in the current stage, the user can retrieve the saved values on only the same GAS project." this means the user needs access to the GAS project right? So my question is, if the user somehow can retrieve this token somehow and use this for getting access to services he should not have access to.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Yes. I think that your understanding is correct. I think that when for the standalone GAS project, when the users have no permission for writing the script, in the current stage, the users cannot directly see the access token (In this case, users cannot use log.), while the script can use the user's access token. But I'm not sure whether this is the perfect security you expect. So I would like to propose that you test the various situations you think. By this, how about obtaining the result?

Comment: Thank you, I think this is sufficient. The use case was basically that "curious" users are able to get the token somehow and do some things they are not supposed to do ;)

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I summarized my comments as an answer. Could you please confirm it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the discussions on the comments, I would like to propose the following answer as the current answer.

### Q1

> Can the user access this token somewhere (afaik there is no UI in the Gsuite for that?)

A: When `PropertiesService.getUserProperties()` is used, the user can retrieve the saved values on only the same GAS project. And, it seems that the values cannot be retrieved with the Google APIs and UI. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/properties#comparison_of_property_stores)

### Q2

> What can the user actually do with this token (I think it will expire in 1 hour right?)

A: At Google, the default value of `expires_in` of the access token is 3600 seconds. About this, you can check this using the following curl command.

```
curl "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/tokeninfo?access_token=###"
```

### Q3

> if the user somehow can retrieve this token somehow and use this for getting access to services he should not have access to.

A: For the standalone GAS project, when the users have no permission for writing the script, the users cannot directly see the access token (In this case, users cannot use the log.), while the script can use the user's access token.

### Note:

- Above situation is for July 10, 2020. Google Apps Script and Google APIs are growing now. So these specification might be changed in the future update. Please be careful this. When I could confirm the specification was changed, I would like to update this answer.